# Algebraic manipulations on inequations

Tags: linear-algebra

I was curious about an inequation :

$2n \ge 0$

Can i add a positive integer to obtain this :

$2n + 2 \geq 0$

Or do i must write it like :

$2n + 2 > 0$

More generally, can i do some algebraic manipulation only on the left or the write side of the inequation ?

Thanks !

Comment: $2n\ge 0 \implies 2n+2\ge 2>0$ so both $2n+2\ge 0$ and $2n+2>0$ are true, but $2n+2>0$ is more powerful result.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can, as long as you add something non-negative on the left hand side, or non-positive in the right hand side.

For the choice of symbol: both are correct, but when adding something strictly positive putting the strict inequality symbol gives more information. (Similarly on the RHS)

Comment: Is there a theorem or something like that to justify this algebraic manipulation ?

Comment: It's rather a definition issue: there is nothing to be proved